# Meaning of a sentence in A History of Britain about Edward I

Tags: meaning, british-english, sentence, books

I faced this paragraph in "A History of Britain" by Simon Schama:

> In the summer of 1263 the situation became critical. De Montfort and
> his allies had captured most of southeastern England. Henry had
> retreated in fright to the Tower of London, doubtless relieved that he
> had added those new walls to its defences. To raise money to pay the
> mercenary troops in the royal army the queen had pawned her jewels to
> the Templars. **On the pretext of inspecting or possibly redeeming
> them, Edward talked his way into the New Temple, where he proceeded to
> stage a bank robbery, smashing the treasure chests and relieving the
> Templars of their gold and silver.** It was a classic Edwardian stunt,
> but its effect was to convert the mayor and burgesses of London from
> cool sceptics of the Montfortians into unreserved allies. What, after
> all, was the point of supporting the forces of order if they were
> themselves the leading criminals? Taken off their leash, the citizenry
> expressed its displeasure against the royalists in the usual ways. The
> fact that the queen was not only the patroness of the hated
> ‘foreigners’ but also enjoyed the proceeds from several prime tolls in
> the city made her an especially choice target. Fearing the worst,
> Eleanor attempted to break out of London by river and get to Edward’s
> army at Windsor. But her boat was recognized and pelted with stones
> and ordure from the crowds standing on London Bridge, the site of her
> most lucrative toll stations. Mortified by the humiliation, she was
> forced to take refuge in St Paul’s. It was an affront that neither she
> nor Edward would ever forget or forgive.

What exactly the emboldened part means? I don't want to know just the meaning. A bit more information on: how does it mean what it means?

Isn't it a bit ambiguous for the native speakers too?

Also I think I need a very brief background/foreground info about the incident for a better understanding.

---

Edit:

For the ambiguity:

I wasn't sure what Edward I actually did. How Did he robbed the jewels? Did he stole them secretly or with force or what? Did he acted like it was some thieves (What's "smashing" for)? How they found out it was him (if the text suggests something)?

Also, "redeeming" means?

Comment: You might do better asking this over on History SE, since the explanation owes more to the history and geography of London, than it does to the English language.

Comment: I know little about this period of history, but I don't see any ambiguity. The Queen had pawned her jewels (given them as security for a loan of money) to the Knights Templar. Edward (presumably her son) made an excuse to enter the Templars' headquarters and robbed them of their valuables.

Comment: This has been difficult to decide. It's complicated. After a lot of research, I'm not sure where to ask such questions. But it's mainly about English language. I am a linguaphile and guessed maybe answers of this site's users is more relevant to what I want. @KillingTime

Comment: I don't see the ambiguity you think exists. If you explained *why* you think the sentence is ambiguous — i.e., what the two possibilities for its meaning are — maybe we could help you.

Comment: @PeterShor I did it.

Comment: Edward _talked his way in_ (so they knew he was there). He _staged a bank robbery_ by _smashing_ (breaking up) the treasure chests. Doesn't that make it clear that he did it openly and by force? (It doesn't say what happened to his mother's jewels, but presumably he took those back as well as helping himself to gold and silver.)

Comment: This is common irony: "*relieving* the Templars of their gold and silver" is like saying "Let me help you with that heavy necklace by taking it as mine." No one will really say "Thank you, that was heavy and I am relieved."

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks for the comments. "staging" is something related to actors imho. I was thinking maybe Edward made some changes in the scene to pretend it was some other thieves and not him.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, _stage_ can mean 'put on a performance', but it can also mean 'organise' or 'cause to happen'. I think if Schama had meant that Edward faked a robbery by unknown thieves, he would have explained it in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word [pawned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pawnbroker)  means that he got a loan, leaving some valuable objects as collateral. If he did not repay the loan within a certain amount of time then the pawnbroker could keep the items.

Redeeming, in this context, means the act of repaying the loan plus any interest and recovering his collateral.

The highlighted passage means that he entered the temple, promising that he was about to redeem the loan, but then took the Templars' money by force.

And saying that he "staged" a robbery just means that he robbed them. It doesn't indicate that he made any false performance, or claimed that other people had robbed them.